# jQuery tablesorter page addon does not work

Tags: jquery, tablesorter, pager

I included the latest tablesorter.js and tablesorter.pager.js into my html file. I also have jQuery 1.9.1 included. Unfortunately if I load the page Firebug says that there is a type error:

```
TypeError: $.browser is undefined
```

I think $.browser is part of the jQuery. So, is 1.9.1 not compatible with the pager addon? The tablesorter alone works great, only the pager does not work.

Comment: Try [this fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$.browser` was removed in jQuery 1.9 Read http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

#### Update

Try

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match("MSIE")) {
```

instead of

```
if ($.browser.msie) {
```

Comment: so, that means,  tablesorterpager is not compatible with 1.9?

Comment: I don't think so, http://tablesorter.com/addons/pager/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js I dont see any references to $.browser here

Comment: If you see http://tablesorter.com/__jquery.tablesorter.js, its only being used once. you can replace that condition with another check

Comment: Can you provide another check? I don't know how you can rewrite this.

Comment: @tester added in the answer